# Has the USA ever taken unilateral military action?

Tags: united-states, military

In the post-American Revolution era, has the United States ever taken unilateral military action against another country besides during the Civil War?

Comment: I know this looks trivial to answer, but IMHO this is the kind of question it would be good to have an answer to here.

Comment: The question is very poorly researched, and could benefit from engaging with the theories of sovereignty and government that exist.

Comment: Could even be considered asking for a list, which is specifically a type of question not to ask.

Comment: I agree with @T.E.D.. The op is not asking for a list. She/he is just asking if it has happened before. I think it is a very valid (though trivial) question.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, the USA has frankly engaged in unilateral military action so many times, it would be serious work just to count them all.

Just among [declared wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_war_by_the_United_States#Declarations_of_war), three of the five (a bare majority) were one-on-one wars that the USA declared first.

Among non-declared wars, this has been a common scenario. Presidents Reagan and Bush in the 1980s engaged in 3 of them that I can think of off the top of my head ([Grenada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Grenada), [Panama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Panama), and the [Libyan bombing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_United_States_bombing_of_Libya)).

Interestingly the [official Marine hymn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marines%27_Hymn) mentions two such military actions in the first line: The [Mexican/American War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican-American_War), and the [First Barbary War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Barbary_War).

Comment: -1 for Grenada. It was not "unilateral military action" - it was undertaken on the request of legitimate government after a coup. As per Wikipedia: "Media outside the U.S. covered the invasion in a negative outlook despite the OAS request for intervention (on the request of the U.S. government), Soviet and Cuban presence on the island and the presence of American medical students at the True Blue Medical Facility." Same story as Clinton's Haiti invasion.

Comment: @DVK I don't really care to reargue the politics of that invasion here. *At the time* the entire rest of the world (as well as a large portion of the USA) [viewed it as a unilateral US military action](http://www.un.org/documents/ga/res/38/a38r007.htm).  That's good enough for me.

Comment: @DVK Have you been reading this? https://openanthropology.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/grenadacia.pdf

Comment: @T.E.D. that's patently false. Many countries in the region supported the invasion of Grenada both politically _and militarily_. "[T]he assault was staged by at least 500 United States marines and army rangers and 300 soldiers from Barbados, Jamaica, Antigua, St. Vincent's, St. Lucia, Dominica and St. Kitts- Nevis" [(NYT)](http://www.nytimes.com/1983/10/26/world/1900-us-troops-with-caribbean-allies-invade-grenada-fight-leftist-units-moscow.html)

Answer (score 5):

To name just a few of the better-known instances:

1. Canada and Britain in 1812;
2. Cuba<sup>1</sup> in 1898;
3. Assorted Indian *Nations* throughout the 19th century: Sioux, Apache, Cheyenne, etc.; and
4. Grenada in 1983;

Notes:

1. The unilateral action was ***not against Spain***, at least in a technical sense. Congress took unilateral action in support of Cuban independence, upon which Spain declared war on the U.S.

Comment: @Tea Drinker: Thank you - I did intend the island nation and not the camp.

Comment: The Indian nations don't count as a "country", if we take the question at face value. But certainly in principle you are correct.

Comment: @Vector - Debatable. However, ignoring those does not significanly alter the answer either.

Comment: as there were no Indian NATIONS, just tribal groups scattered around the continent, that indeed doesn't count. Calling them "nations" is modern politically correct nonsense designed to give legitimacy to the tax excempt status of indian tribal casinos and licquor stores.

Comment: +1 For mentioning Indian nations. Not counting them as countries/nations is racist "Flag Imperialism". http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYeFcSq7Mxg

Comment: isn't listing Canada and Britain in 1812 a little unfair, the British were impressing American sailors into service.

Comment: @Ryathal: That is what US history books claim; the accusation is disputed.

Comment: Even if the US was provoked, it would still be unilateral.  Unilateral just means we acted alone, without a coalition or allies.

Comment: Let me understand your note.  If the US should take unilateral military action to "free Quebec" you wouldn't consider that military action against the country of Canada?